# Arranging barplots from seaborn in array

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, seaborn

I am trying to make a plot in seaborn for every category which occurs in column 'Category' in my df. There are 7 unique categories. I managed to do this in one row but the plots are too small. I would like to fit them into two rows (4 in first and 3 in seven). How shall I change the code apart from the fact that I am supposed to change the arguments of subplots to (2,4)?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 7)

for i,g in enumerate(df.Category.unique()):
    dfx = df[df['Category'] == g]
    sns.set(style="whitegrid", rc={'figure.figsize':(28,6)})
    sns.barplot(x = dfx['Month'], y = dfx['measure'], ci = None, label = g, ax=ax[i])
    ax[i].legend(loc = 'lower center')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the flattened axes array and also use `groupby` to simplyfy things. So I'd say the code can look like this (untested because no data provided in the question):

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 4)

for (n, dfx), ax in zip(df.groupby("Category"), axes.flat):
    sns.barplot(x = dfx['Month'], y = dfx['measure'], ci = None, label = n, ax=ax)
    ax.legend(loc = 'lower center')

axes[1,3].axis("off")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Also, as you seem to be using seaborn, you may consider a `seaborn.FacetGrid`.
This could look like

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col = "Category", col_wrap=4)
g.map(sns.barplot, "Month", "measure")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```